# Magmi CLI appears to run but no products imported

Tags: php, magento, command-line-interface, magmi

Like the title says, magmi cli appears to run (it pauses for a period of time and then returns to the prompt) but no products are imported. I can run the profile from the web interface and everything works as expected but the same profile with cli results in nothing. My command:

php magmi.cli.php -profile=tmb -create

I get no feedback, just returned to the prompt and I get the same result on two separate servers - all good with web but no products with cli. Anyone have a clue what could cause this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some more information about how you have your Magmi configured and possibly a line or two from your import file?

Comment: I'm not allowed to answer my own question but it was an incorrect command. Had been a long day and I couldn't see that I was missing the 'mode' flag. Should have been:

php magmi.cli.php -profile=tmb -mode=create

Works fine now.

Comment: ha!  I've dealt with Magmi a lot recently but didn't catch that either.  I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: Thanks Sean. In case anyone stumbles across this post in the future, I should also add that if I had thought to check magmi/state/progress.txt I would have seen that the wrong mode was being used.

Comment: I know this is old, but I just hit the same issue with a different cause.  The Profile I was using pointed to a different directory which did not contain my file. (when using the -CSV:filename parameter).   Switched to the "right" profile pointing at the right directory, and all is good.